# running java program from python script

Tags: python, subprocess

[image]

I am trying to use a python script to

1) getting the Pid of a java program and,
2) using that pid to run JVMRuntimeClient.class

but nothing is happening

Here is my script:-

```
import subprocess
import os

process = subprocess.Popen('java -cp .Workspace.TestProject.bin.VirtualMemorySimulatorPart3')
pid=str(process.pid)
os.popen('java .Workspace.TestProject.bin.JVMRuntimeClient -pid' + pid)
print(pid)
exit()
```

Comment: I think you're not using right the -cp option. Turn to the official documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
  If you're specifying -cp option, you should specify both the class path and the Main containing class name.