# Pass multiple list of parameters from python to java program and get back return code using subprocess.communicate

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, subprocess

Need some help with following code - I want to pass string elements of three list as input to java program that I am calling in my python script. Here is what I have done so far -

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import Popen

amount = ['23.5', '12.5', '56.0', '176.1']
invoice_no = ['11290', '12892', '12802', '23489']
date = ['2/3/19', '12/30/17', '04/21/2018', '8/12/17', '12/21/18']

## problem is proc.communicate(). I am currently passing only invoice_no[i] as input.

for i in range (0, len(invoice_no)):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '/data/python/xyz.jar'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    q = proc.communicate(input = invoice_no[i])
    print(q)
## But I want to pass amount and date as input as well. 
## I dont know the syntax for that. I also want output as 1 or 0 i.e success or failure. Does anyone know syntax for this?
```

Most of the questions which I have seen are passing single string as input.But that's not what I am looking for. Even official document of subprocess is not helpful in finding out how to pass multiple inputs syntax. Links are - [running java program from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380168/running-java-program-from-python-script)

[How to execute java program using python considering inputs and outputs both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333637/how-to-execute-java-program-using-python-considering-inputs-and-outputs-both?rq=1)

Comment: Shouldn't `-jar` argument should also be a separate parameter to Popen?

Comment: Not exactly sure.. I am new to python. I was able to reach this after going through many questions and documents.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have found answer. I thought I will post it here. May be someone will find it useful -

```
   import subprocess
   from subprocess import PIPE
   from subprocess import Popen

   amount = ['23.5', '12.5', '56.0', '176.1']
   invoice_no = ['11290', '12892', '12802', '23489']
   date = ['2/3/19', '12/30/17', '04/21/2018', '8/12/17', '12/21/18']
   for i in range (0, len(invoice_no)):
       proc = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '/data/python/xyz.jar', invoice_no[i], date[i], amount[i]],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
       output = proc.communicate()[0] ## this will capture the output of script called in the parent script.
```